# I am having trouble with trying to have my computer calculate income on java

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to make my computer develop a popup window to ask for my hourly pay, then the hours I worked and the total I will have after taxes (15%) Im not really sure what I keep doing wrong...

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;    
public class payrollAdam    
{    
public static void main(String[] args)   
{   
String hourpay, hours, total,result;  
double tax;  
double tax = .15;  
int total = result * tax;  
hourpayString = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( "what is your hourly pay?" , "enter hour pay ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);   
hoursString = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( "how much time worked?" , "hours spent:", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  
resultString = hourpay * hours;  
totalString = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ("");  
System.exit(0);    
}    
}
```

when I try to compile it states (lines 9 & 10) that the variables "tax" "total" and "income" have already been defined in method "main(String[])" The other errors on line 11: "'*' is a bad operand type for binary operator" and that my methods for showmessagedialog are not suitable (string string integer) also on line 11

Comment: Tell us what problems your code is having. You tell us that it's not working but don't tell us any details. Instead you're posting text at the bottom of your code that doesn't help us understand your problem in the least.

Comment: @Adam You are using String data type for all the numeric input (as in hourpay * hours) use int or double also you have declared tax twice in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a mess of errors -- you're declaring variables as Strings, then re-declaring the same variables, something not allowed.

Start over, declare your variables once and only once, and with the proper type, and it will likely work. Start by getting rid of:

```
String hourpay, hours, total,result;  
double tax;
```

Also when your code has a ton of compiler errors, this tells you that your method of creating code is wrong. You should never try to add good code to bad. Always compile early and often and fix all compiler errors before trying to add new code. If you use an IDE such as Eclipse or NetBeans, you'll be flagged immediately if any compiler errors should occur.

Also in the future when asking questions about compiler errors or run time exceptions, always post those error messages with your question. They're important, they often tell you **exactly** what is wrong. Your lack of this key information is likely why your question was down-voted.